# How to deploy a Go program on amazon ec2 without compiling it on ec2?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am looking for a way to deploy the go binary on amazon ec2. Currently all the tutorials I have found ([1](http://www.blog.labouardy.com/deploying-go-app-to-aws-ec2/), [2](https://medium.com/@nathanborror/deploying-a-go-project-on-ec2-15ce381cf7a1)) are explaining how to move the go sources on ec2 and to compile them there.

This is not what I am looking for for a couple of reasons. Among them:

- I do not want to copy all the sources
- I do not want to install irrelevant binaries (go compiler and other things)

In my opinion this is unnecessary because go has an ability to [cross-compile binaries](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling). I think that is is better to build a binary locally and to upload it on ec2.

Am I missing something here, are there any hidden pitfalls with my approach or is there a better way?

P.S. if this question is better suited for serverfault, please let me know or move it there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are right. One of the selling points of Go is cross-compiling into a single binary file. It's better to compile at localhost then copy it to your server.

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o my_app .
$ scp my_app ec2@ip:~
```

Comment: In my case, I also needed to disable `cgo` by adding `CGO_ENABLED=0`

Answer (score 0):

[Official sample](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-go/2-deploy.sh) from AWS does it this way:

```
GOOS=linux go build -tags lambda.norpc -o bootstrap main.go
```

Then create a zip file to upload:

```
zip awslambda.zip bootstrap
```